# Two unstable queries performance

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database, relationship

I'm really confused about this two queries, they are have unstable query speed. Here is my two table scheme;

Posts table: (id, title, date etc...) [date index]

Relationships table: (news_id, relation_id) [both and per row have indexes]

Query A:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT news_id
    FROM relationships
    WHERE relation_id IN (?)
)
AND status = 1
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Query B:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts AS p
INNER JOIN relationships AS r ON r.news_id = n.id
WHERE r.relation_id IN (?)
AND n.status = 1
ORDER BY n.date DESC
```

Now weird part is tests results; first trying a relation_id which has 30 rows;

Query A: 30 total, Query took 5.56 sec

Query B: 30 total, Query took 0.03 sec

A is slow on less rows, B is speed on less rows. Next trying a relation_id wich has 3k rows;

Query A: 3,850 total, Query took 0.05 sec

Query B: 3,850 total, Query took 0.70 sec

So this is confused me, with more data now A is more fast. And last one, trying multi relation_id with +10k rows; example; `relation_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)`

Query A: 18,906 total, Query took 0.01 sec

Query B: 18,906 total, Query took 3.34 sec

So what should I do? Query A is speed on so much rows but slow with less rows. Any another true way suggestion for this query? *(sorry for my bad English or grammatical mistakes)*

**EDIT**

Here is SQL EXPLAIN s ;

Query A with 30 rows
[image: Query A with 30 rows]

Query B with 30 rows
[image: query B]

Query A with 18k rows
[image: query a]

Query B with 18k rows
[image: query b 2]

Comment: Could you give the explain for the 30-row-example and for a big example? The `where in` should not take 5 seconds. Are you sure no other queries where disturbing you measurements? Is it repeatable?

Comment: Does `posts.id` have an index on it?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes, its primary

Comment: I think you'll need to use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) on the queries and post the result. Anything else is pretty much guessing.

Comment: @flaschenpost like that; http://pastebin.com/1aN4JcjC

Comment: instead of `SELECT ...` you can do an `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, and that output gives you much information about the query execution plan. Those `EXPLAIN`s are needed.

Comment: ok, I added EXPLAIN s.

Comment: @musa You may want to try an `ANALYZE TABLE posts` and retry the query.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson analyze status is ok, and still same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange, but that's MySQL ;-)

The optimizer thinks that `status = 1` is a strong restriction. If that holds, you get by

```
select status=1, count(*) as num from posts group by status=1
```

If just a small part of your table has `status=1` then the 30-row solution still is quite good from mysqls point of view.

If a big part has `status = 1` then you should try the query with

```
from posts ignore index (status) ...
```

or

```
from posts force index (id) ...
```

to enforce the where-in-solution.

More information you can get via

```
explain select count(*) from relationships where relation_id in (1)
```

That shows which size the optimizer expects based on it's index statistics.

The problem with fixed index-hints is that they are fixed. That means they apply for the good and for the bad scenarios.

Sometimes a temporary table helps avoiding that, you could store the relevant relations into that.

Comment: actually, I tried without "where status" and "order by", bottleneck looking like ordering. Query B without "order by" took 0.0082 sec with +10k rows